# ScrollMagic parallax effect jerky on all browsers

Tags: scroll, parallax, scrollmagic

I have a problem using ScrollMagic to do parallax scrolling: When scrolling, the background images are jerky instead of scrolling smoothly.
The site in question is this:
https://camilledevillers.fr/site.html

I have noted the problem on all the browsers I have tested (Chrome, Opera, Firefox, Safari).
I also found that with a powerful PC (Ryzen 7 2700x), it did it less than on my i3 laptop (but still a little).

Where can the problem come from? Are the images too "big" for ScrollMagic who has trouble doing the calculations? ScrollMagic itself which is not optimized enough? (However, I have seen websites that work very well with it...)

In short, I don't find the reason for these jerks.

Comment: With Windows 10, with any browser, but not with Ubuntu. Very strange. It is visible also in Parallax section example ( https://scrollmagic.io/examples/advanced/parallax_sections.html )
Do you find a solution?